# Is altering a default WordPress database table update safe?

Tags: database, mysql, terms, dbdelta

I want to add some table columns to the `wp_terms` table. Is it safe to use the `dbDelta` function with a modified `CREATE`-MySQL query for this? Or will I run into problems in the long turn? Is it update safe?

As a database rookie I hope someone with more experience can help me out here.

### Background

For a plugin I'm currently working on, I need to add some metadata to a taxonomy term. The first thing is an ordering number and the second is the type of the term. Both are used to sort the posts in the frontend.

In the WordPress codex I've found the action hooks `{taxonomy}_add_form_fields` and `{taxonomy}_edit_form_fields` for this, but unfortunately these saves the metadata in the `wp_options` table as a serialized array. It's probably possible to use the `WHERE REGEXP` syntax to query the correct option, but this seems slow and a bit hackish.

Performance matters in the project (A ton of posts assigned to a ton of taxonomy terms) and therefore I'm looking for a way to sort and order the resultset directly on the database layer.

Thanks in advance
Roman

Comment: I'm a db rookie too. However, in this case I've created my own `_termmeta` table and used [Metadata_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) + [WP_Meta_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) for all needs. Yes, a meta query is slower but see the site break after an update is worse. I'm not saying an update will break your site, I'm saying that I, for me, would be scared of this :)

Comment: @G. M. Thank you for your comment. Isn't the Metadata API only for `posts`, `comments` and `users`? Or did you mean I should store the term metadata in the `wp_postmeta` table?

Comment: Metadata API can be used for custom tables too. Cite from codex: _"Some desired $meta_types do not come with pre-installed WordPress tables, and so they must be created manually"_

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you. I will try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbDelta` is squirrelly. Some things it will alter, others it will not. For example, and if I remember correctly, you can add indexes to tables but not change those indexes or delete them. I honestly don't know if it will remove table columns. (My guess it that it won't but I may test that later.)

Nonetheless, I would not do something as critical as add columns of data to a Core table. Even if `dbDelta` leaves those columns alone, WordPress may (please please please) eventually adopt a more flexible database tool and that might remove your columns. Don't do it.

If you can't use the options table or postmeta or another table as it is intended to be used, create your own meta table for the taxonomies. WordPress, and `dbDelta` will leave that alone. Of course, you will have to deal with the SQL to retrieve that data but you were looking at having to do that anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I've already thought about using my own table, but this would require a lot more work for the CRUD part of the application. I will leave the question open for a while to hear other peoples opinions.

Comment: WordPress won't know how to deal with your extra columns so you are already looking at roughly the same work, just different work.

Comment: You're completely right. I've misunderstood your last paragraph. I thought you mean I should create my own `wp_terms` table and not only a `wp_termmeta` table. Sorry for that.

Comment: :) Yes, no need to re-create the entire terms system.