# Extending the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add an extra column to the comments database which will store the user ID of the post/page author. This is part of a plugin which will display new comments in reply to either a post or another comment. As far as I can see Wordpress doesn't have this functionality built in but rather places comments in one large group. I want users to quickly see only comments relevant to themselves.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();       
$query = "ALTER TABLE $wpdb->comments ADD replyto_who bigint(20)";
if ( maybe_add_column($wpdb->comments,'replyto_who',$query) ) {
    $query = "SELECT comment_post_ID,comment_ID FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE replyto_who IS NULL";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    foreach ( $results as $result ) {
        $user_id = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_author FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = $result->comment_post_ID" );
        if ( isset($user_id) )
            $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->comments SET replyto_who='$user_id' WHERE comment_ID=$result->comment_ID");
    }
}
```

Please note above code is only for testing.

The problem I'm having is that the new entry is always being given a value of '1' after a new comment is entered even though the above code hasn't run. Looking at the table structure using `phpMyAdmin` I see the column has `Null=yes` and `default=NULL`. Being new to SQL I'm not quite sure what I'm doing.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I would not recommend this. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111835/21376

Comment: @s_ha_dum Is there an alternative you could recommend? I honestly believe this column should be part of the core. As it stands, to find the post author requires first fetching the comment_post_ID then an additional lookup to find the post_author. Thinking about it, I suppose it could be done with INNER MERGE.

Comment: If you think it needs to be in the Core, then [submit a ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) preferably with a patch and hope for the best, but don't modify a Core table on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting a 1. Your code says that you should not. However, it seems that what you're doing is unnecessary and generally ill-advised. Modifying existing tables is usually not needed.

The wp_comments table contains a comment_parent and user_id column.

So if I reply to a comment, it's immediate parent ID is in comment_parent and that comments author ID is in user_id if they are logged in (0 otherwise).

You could also use the wp_commentmeta to store this information if I've misunderstood.