# How to add additional field in a table row after creating a table?

Tags: plugin-development, database

I used options for my plugins.But now i have changed to use own table.i created and using things good.Now i would like to add one field that gets value from user and add that much value as field.This is like adding field dynamically.Example in options table i used the below

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= get_option('opt_count'); $i++) {
            register_setting('register_op', 'option' . $i);
        }
```

So if the user enter 3 in opt_count then i'll get 3 extra option by registering.Then i'll make use of the 3 fields. 
Same thing i want to do it in own table also.

```
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    message text NOT NULL,
    no_url VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
     );";
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
```

Here when the user enter 3 in no_url option then i have to make 3 extra field where user can enter the 1st url in option one and 2nd url in option two going on..

How to do this.. I Think this is not easier as options method.Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Since you are out of realm of WP APIs really I think this boils down to figuring out table modification with SQL. Better asked at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks.Can i ask the clone of this in SO?

Comment: I am not _entirely_ sure if I understand question correctly. Are you talking about creating SQL table itself or creating values in existing table?

Comment: Creating a Column kind of thing in exsisting table.Like field to hold values.using one field value(4) i should be able to create  4 field in the same row.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113319/extending-the-database

Comment: Thanks but i want to create number of columns as user specify.if user specify 5 then i have to add 5 column

Comment: If you're needing to add an indeterminate number of columns to a table, you're doing it wrong. why not use a custom post type and meta data?